# Error: "No usable mining devices" despite benchmark is ok

Tags: ethminer, ubuntu

I am new here, and this is my first question.

I have just installed ethminer on ubuntu 20.04 and it seems that everything is ok in the settings:

1. The command  `ethminer --list-devices`  gives

```
ethminer 0.19.0-17+commit.ce52c740
Build: linux/release/gnu

 Id Pci Id    Type Name                          CUDA SM   Total Memory 
--- --------- ---- ----------------------------- ---- ---  ------------ 
  0 03:00.0   Gpu  GeForce GTX 1070              Yes  6.1       7.37 GB
```

2. Running a benchmark with the commad `ethminer -G -M 0` works well
3. Moreover `clinfo` gives the following

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 11.2.109
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
```

Nevertheless when I try to really run ethminer  by typing for example:

```
ethminer -G --report-hr -P stratum1+tcp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.@eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999
```

then I get:

```
ethminer 0.19.0-17+commit.ce52c740
Build: linux/release/gnu

Error: No usable mining devices found
```

Do you have any idea on what is happening here?

Comment: Did you found a solution?
can you post it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change -G for -U. This worked for me.

Comment: Hello. While this might answer the question, more details would be nice to understand why this works.